# How to check if nvidia-gpu is available using bash script?

Tags: bash, nvidia

I want to do this

```sh
if nvidia-gpu available; then
    do something
else
    do something-else
fi
```

How can i achieve this using bash script?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if a program exists from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/how-can-i-check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script)

Comment: @iBug, The actual question is what command should i use to validate if gpu is available or not?. Ex: nvidia-smi or nvcc, but these commands will always be available if you have gpu plugged in or not, so we cannot use this.

Comment: nvidia-smi reports required information

Answer (score 1):

It depends a little on your system and the tools installed. If, e. g., you can use `lshw`, this would possibly be enough:

```sh
if [[ $(lshw -C display | grep vendor) =~ Nvidia ]]; then
  do something
else
  do something-else
fi
```

Explanation:

- `lshw` lists your hardware devices
- `-C display` limits this to display charachteristics only
- `grep vendor` filters out the line containing vendor specification
- `=~ Nvidia` checks if that line matches the expression "Nvidia"

If you can't use `lshw` you might be able to achieve something similar using `lspci` or reading values from the `/proc` file system.

It might be possible, that for this to work you need to have working Nvidia drivers installed for the graphics card. But I assume, your use case wouldn't make sense without them anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

If `lspci` is available/acceptable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Some distro requires that the absolute path is given when invoking lspci
# e.g. /sbin/lspci if the user is not root.
gpu=$(lspci | grep -i '.* vga .* nvidia .*')

shopt -s nocasematch

if [[ $gpu == *' nvidia '* ]]; then
  printf 'Nvidia GPU is present:  %s\n' "$gpu"
  echo do_this
else
  printf 'Nvidia GPU is not present: %s\n' "$gpu"
  echo do_that
fi
```

Things get more complicated when dealing with dual GPU's like Optimus and the likes.

```
lspci | grep -i vga
```

Output

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 3 GB Max-Q] (rev a1)
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso (rev c2)
```

One work around is to count how many GPU's is/are available.

```
lspci | grep -ci vga
```

Output

```
2
```

Just add another test if there are more than one VGA output.

```
total=$(lspci | grep -ci vga)

if ((total > 1)); then
  echo "$total"
  echo do_this
fi
```

I'm Using GNU `grep` so, not sure if that flag will work on non GNU grep.

Answer (score 0):

When it is loaded with `modprobe` or `insmod` then you can do something like...

```
(lsmod | grep -q nameofyourdriver) && echo 'already there' || echo 'load it'
```